# making rows to column and saved in separate files

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 4 text file in a folder and each text file contain many rows of data as follows

```
cat a.txt
10.0000 0.0000 10.0000 0.0000           
11.0000 0.0000 11.0000 0.0000

cat b.txt
5.1065 3.8423 2.6375 3.5098
4.7873 5.9304 1.9943 4.7599

cat c.txt
3.5257 3.9505 3.8323 4.3359
3.3414 4.0014 4.0383 4.4803

cat d.txt
1.8982 2.0342 1.9963 2.1575
1.8392 2.0504 2.0623 2.2037
```

I want to make each corresponding rows of the text file to column as

file001.txt

```
10.0000  5.1065  3.5257  1.8982
 0.0000  3.8423  3.9505  2.0342
10.0000  2.6375  3.8323  1.9963
 0.0000  3.5098  4.3359  2.1575
```

file002.txt

```
11.0000  4.7873  3.3414  1.8329
 0.0000  5.9304  4.0014  2.0504
11.0000  1.9943  4.0383  2.0623
 0.0000  4.7599  4.4803  2.2037
```

Anf finally I want to add this value  `5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000` to every line so the final output should be

file001.txt

```
10.0000  5.1065  3.5257  1.8982 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 0.0000  3.8423  3.9505  2.0342 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
10.0000  2.6375  3.8323  1.9963 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 0.0000  3.5098  4.3359  2.1575 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
```

file002.txt

```
11.0000  4.7873  3.3414  1.8329 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 0.0000  5.9304  4.0014  2.0504 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
11.0000  1.9943  4.0383  2.0623 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 0.0000  4.7599  4.4803  2.2037 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
```

Finally, I want to append some comments on the top of every created files

So for example file001.txt should be

```
# 
# ascertain thin
# Metamorphs
# pch
# what is that
# 5-r
# Add the thing
# liop34
# liop36
# liop45
# liop34
# M(CM)   N(M)   O(S) P(cc)   ab       cd       efgh       ijkl       mnopq    rstuv
#
10.0000  5.1065  3.5257  1.8982 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 0.0000  3.8423  3.9505  2.0342 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
10.0000  2.6375  3.8323  1.9963 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
 0.0000  3.5098  4.3359  2.1575 5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
files = ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "d.txt"]

# get number of columns per file, i.e., 4 in sample data
n_each = np.loadtxt(files[0]).shape[1]

# concatanate transposed data
arrays = np.concatenate([np.loadtxt(file).T for file in files])

# rows are in column now for easier reshaping; reshape and save
n_all = arrays.shape[1]
for n in range(n_all):
    np.savetxt(f"file{str(n+1).zfill(3)}.txt",
               arrays[:, n].reshape(n_each, len(files)).T,
               fmt="%7.4f")
```

---

to add a fixed array of values right to the new arrays, you can perform horizontal stacking after tiling the new values n_each times:

```py
# other things same as above
new_values = np.tile([5, 6, 9, 0, 1, 1], (n_each, 1))
for n in range(n_all):
    np.savetxt(f"file{str(n+1).zfill(3)}.txt",
               np.hstack((arrays[:, n].reshape(n_each, len(files)).T,
                          new_values)),
               fmt="%7.4f")
```

---

to add comments, `header` and `comments` parameters of np.savetxt is useful. we pass the string to `header` and since it already contains "# " in it, we suppress extra "# " from np.savetxt by passing comments="":

```py
comment = """\
# 
# ascertain thin
# Metamorphs
# pch
# what is that
# 5-r
# Add the thing
# liop34
# liop36
# liop45
# liop34
# M(CM)   N(M)   O(S) P(cc)   ab       cd       efgh       ijkl       mnopq    rstuv
#"""

# rows are in column now for easier reshaping; reshape and save
n_all = arrays.shape[1]
new_values = np.tile([5, 6, 9, 0, 1, 1], (n_each, 1))
for n in range(n_all):
    np.savetxt(f"file{str(n+1).zfill(3)}.txt",
               np.hstack((arrays[:, n].reshape(n_each, len(files)).T,
                          new_values)),
               fmt="%7.4f",
               header=comment,
               comments="")
```

Comment: Aydin If i want to add  every line "5.0000 6.0000 9.0000 0.0000 1.0000 1.0000"  then how to do it, please update the answer if possible.

Comment: aydin can you plz have a look into my updated question.

Comment: Finally i want to add some comments on every created file, can you please help me solving this. I updated the question. can you plz look into it.

Comment: well you can pass `header="comment this and that"` to `np.savetxt` for that

Comment: if possible plz add few lines of code in your answer, plz.

Comment: added that. note that if your comments already have "# " in front, you need to pass comments="" because numpy puts "# " also otherwise